# Pagina PHP não identifica resultado de SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma página PHP para mostrar informações do banco de dados, porém ela não dá erro e só retorna "`:0`" na página, como se não tivesse vindo nenhum resultado do `SELECT` (só entra no `else`).

Segue o código:

```
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") 
    or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados");      
    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($conexao,"mentoria"); 
    $campos = array(".", "-");      

    $cpf = str_replace($campos,"",$_POST["inputCPF"]);

    $consulta_jovens = "SELECT jCPF AS jovem, ((CASE WHEN jovem.jfaixaetaria = mentor.mfaixaetaria THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jescolaridade = mentor.mescolaridade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jhobby = mentor.mhobby THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcomida = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jmusica = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jesporte = mentor.mesporte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jtime = mentor.mtime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcaracteristica = mentor.mcaracteristica THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.janimal = mentor.manimal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jlivro = mentor.mlivro THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jsonho = mentor.msonho THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS qtdCaracteristicasIguais FROM jovem INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado WHERE mentor.mcidade = jovem.jcidade AND mentor.mestado   = jovem.jestado AND mentor.CPF ='$cpf'";

    $string_sql = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE CPF='$cpf'";  

    $result= mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql); 

    $resultadojovens = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta_jovens);

    $dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    
    $aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens);

    $alunosel = $aluno['qtdCaracteristicasIguais'];
    $nome = $dado['mnome'];     

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) == 1){ 
        echo "<p><h2>Olá, $nome! <br><br> Escolha o seu mentorando abaixo:</h2></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>$resultadojovens</p>";

    } else {
        echo mysqli_errno($conexao) . ": " . mysqli_error($conexao) . "\n";
    }

    mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema é o uso desta função:

```
mysqli_affected_rows
```

O `mysqli_affected_rows` serve para obter o número de alterações de um `DELETE` ou `UPDATE`, ou para identificar se a operação é um `REPLACE` que inseriu ou que só atualizou.

Se quiser o número de linhas retornado por um `SELECT` deve usar isto:

```
mysqli_num_rows
```

Talvez seja o caso de usar `if(mysqli_num_rows($conexao))` sem o `==1` para que o `if` entre na primeira condição mesmo se o número de linhas for maior que zero, não apenas uma só.

Comment: Obrigada, Bacco! Resolveu meu problema!